# Broken text in LaTeX table using tabular

Tags: latex, overleaf

I have a table in LaTeX using OverLeaf and text inside it is very spaced in some columns, I don't know what's causing this issue and would really appreciate some feedback.

[image: Table in LaTeX]

```
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.5cm}{0cm}
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=1.3\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|p{4cm}|}
\hline
 & \textbf{Unity} & \textbf{Unreal Engine 4} & \textbf{Godot} & \textbf{CryEngine} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Cena} & Darmowa dla małych projektów, płatna subskrypcja dla większych & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków & Darmowy, open-source & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków \\
 \hline
 \textbf{3D/2D} & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D, choć 2D jest możliwe & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Łatwość użycia} & Relatywnie łatwe dla początkujących & Wymaga więcej nauki niż Unity, ale ma mocne narzędzia & Prosty interfejs, łatwy do nauki & Wymaga więcej nauki, interfejs może być trudniejszy dla początkujących \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Język} & C\# & C$++$, Blueprints (wizualne skrypty) & GDScript (podobne do Pythona), C\#, C$++$ & C$++$, Lua \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Asset store} & Bardzo rozbudowany, dziesiątki tysięcy assetów & Tysiące assetów, mniej rozbudowany niż Unity & Mało rozbudowany, assety tworzone przez społeczność & Mniej rozbudowany, ale zawiera wiele wysokiej jakości assetów \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Wsparcie mobile} & Szerokie wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile & Szerokie wsparcie, ale wymaga więcej konfiguracji niż Unity & Wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji & Mniej wsparcia dla platform mobilnych w porównaniu do Unity i Unreal Engine \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Multiplayer} & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej pracy & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{adjustwidth}
\caption{Porównanie różnych aspektów silników gier komputerowych}
\label{tab:tabelaSilniki}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

Several points:

- A `\begin{table}` statement is missing but I assume it is just a missed in the copy/paste and you actually have it in your code
- I don't think adjustwidth and adjustbox environments are necessary here
- Main reason why your columns use so much space if the series of `p{4cm}` commands in column types

One solution would be to use 'auto-width' capability of the `tabularx` package: using `X` as type instead, like so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Porównanie różnych aspektów silników gier komputerowych}
\label{tab:tabelaSilniki}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|X|X|X|}
\hline
 & \textbf{Unity} & \textbf{Unreal Engine 4} & \textbf{Godot} & \textbf{CryEngine} \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Cena} & Darmowa dla małych projektów, płatna subskrypcja dla większych & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków & Darmowy, open-source & Darmowy do pewnego progu przychodów, potem \% zysków \\
 \hline
 \textbf{3D/2D} & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D, choć 2D jest możliwe & Wsparcie dla zarówno 3D jak i 2D & Głównie 3D \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Łatwość użycia} & Relatywnie łatwe dla początkujących & Wymaga więcej nauki niż Unity, ale ma mocne narzędzia & Prosty interfejs, łatwy do nauki & Wymaga więcej nauki, interfejs może być trudniejszy dla początkujących \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Język} & C\# & C$++$, Blueprints (wizualne skrypty) & GDScript (podobne do Pythona), C\#, C$++$ & C$++$, Lua \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Asset store} & Bardzo rozbudowany, dziesiątki tysięcy assetów & Tysiące assetów, mniej rozbudowany niż Unity & Mało rozbudowany, assety tworzone przez społeczność & Mniej rozbudowany, ale zawiera wiele wysokiej jakości assetów \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Wsparcie mobile} & Szerokie wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile & Szerokie wsparcie, ale wymaga więcej konfiguracji niż Unity & Wsparcie dla różnych platform mobile, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji & Mniej wsparcia dla platform mobilnych w porównaniu do Unity i Unreal Engine \\
 \hline
 \textbf{Multiplayer} & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej pracy & Wsparcie dla sieciowego multiplayera, ale może wymagać więcej konfiguracji \\
 \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You are right I didn't paste \begin{table}. adjustwidth and adjustbox are necessary because I'm using my schools form and it has specified margins but I want the table to extend over these margins, unfortunately your solution provided me with totally different solution, but I will try to edit it so that it will fit my needs, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

ChatGPT came with help for this one, that's the solution to my problem:

```
\begin{tabular}{|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{4cm}|}
```